# LibraryImportAttribute incorrectly stating use of extension method and preventing compilation

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, interop, sourcegenerators, .net-8.0

I am using .NET 8 Preview 6 and Visual Studio 2022, updated today.

I updated a library today, changing from `DllImport` to `LibraryImport`, but it indicates `CS0755`.

Here is my imported method declaration:

```
public unsafe static partial class CppCoreFuncs
{
    #region private
    [LibraryImport(DLL, EntryPoint = "Poly2Cofs_multi_buf"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    private static partial FuncResult Poly2CofsMultiBuf(void* buffer, InputMode mode);
    #endrgion

...
}
```

This generates the following code:

```
public unsafe static partial class CppCoreFuncs
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("CPP Core.dll", EntryPoint = "Poly2Cofs_multi_buf", ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern partial global::RWT.ROCT.Core.Public.FuncResult Poly2CofsMultiBuf(void* buffer, global::RWT.ROCT.Core.Public.InputMode mode);
}
```

When I compile, I get this:

> Error CS0755  Both partial method declarations must be extension
> methods or neither may be an extension method...
> Core\Microsoft.Interop.LibraryImportGenerator\Microsoft.Interop.LibraryImportGenerator\LibraryImports.g.cs

Documentation: [Source generation for platform invokes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke-source-generation).

There is no extension method. If I change back to `DLLImport` then the next method import declaration with `LibraryImport` gets this error. It only appears once.

EDIT

For reference, here is a working code generator produced stub for `GeneratedRegexAttribute`:

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Text.RegularExpressions.Generator", "8.0.8.32907")]
    internal static partial global::System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex QuotedOrUnquotedNewLineRx() => global::System.Text.RegularExpressions.Generated.QuotedOrUnquotedNewLineRx_7.Instance;
```

Comment: Possibly. I don't see what attribute is mismatched, though.

Comment: `DLLImportAttribute` is compiler generated. The top code is mine, and the bottom is from the code generator.

Comment: Here is what the specification says: "The attributes in the resulting method declaration are the combined attributes of the defining and the implementing partial method declaration in unspecified order. Duplicates are not removed."

Comment: I still don't get what mistake I'm making, if any. My code looks the same as in the documentation. There is no extension method in either my or the generated code.

Comment: Based on what I read, that source generator should generate a wrapper that takes care of parameter marshalling (in and out), calling the DLL function in between.  So the wrapper function, which should be a c# function, should be a partial method, and then its internal call to the DLL should have a different name.  I don't know why it is generating the DllImport as a partial method.  I guess if it decided no wrapper is needed that could be useful?

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation doesn't give any example of what the generated code should look like.

Comment: The `partial` on the generated code is correct. I upgraded my Regex expression to use the new code generator, and they look similar in style to the code above. But they work. In this case, it looks like a compiler bug of some sort. I have replicated what the instructions state. I have reported it to Microsoft. Will likely need to revert to `DLLImport` for now.

Comment: According to my understanding there should be a partial method in the generated code, but it should be for a wrapper/thunk written in C#.  Not a `DllImport`.  There might also be a `DllImport` which the wrapper calls internally, but that wouldn't be partial.

Comment: I agree since that makes sense.